# Add a window.open as part of teams webhook OpenURI

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-teams, markup

Am trying to add a popup using window.open in teams webhook action, no success till now.
Any help here is much appreciated

```
{"@type": "MessageCard","@context": "http://schema.org/extensions","summary": "test","potentialAction": [{"@type": "OpenUri","name": "Add comment","targets": [{"os": "default","uri": "window.open('http://test.com', 'width=600, height=600')"}]}]}
```

Comment: The usual definition of a "webhook" is, that their servers make a request to yours. Unless you are talking about something else here, your question would make no sense to begin with - they can not make an HTTP request to a "URL" `window.open(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not feasible to add a popup using window.open in teams webhook action.